# Javascript of Nuxt Application Fails to work when deployed on any Platform

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, nuxt.js, cpanel

I have deployed my nuxt application on heroku and through cpanel :
https://blankmedia.in/
https://blank-media.herokuapp.com/

in both of them my javascript fails to work,
for example : button clicks, show and hide divs, carousels, etc
[image: image where carousel typewriter text isn't working]

but when I run it locally everything works as expected.
[image: working image]

my git repo is currently private.

please help

Comment: `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'`, you're using some non-isomorphic code. Nuxt runs your code on both server and client, here you are using some browser-specific methods.

Comment: Also, how do you try it locally? `npm run build && npm run start` or just using `npm run dev`?

Comment: npm run dev -kissu

Comment: that is exactly the error i am getting, plus i dont understand how can i do it unknowingly

Comment: Not sure as of what to say here. Your code is private and it all depends on method you called. Try commenting out some of your code to try to scope it down step by step.